# How to update the RadGridView when the filter is set?

Tags: wpf, xaml, filtering, telerik-grid, radgridview

I have telerik RadGridView with columns "status", "Name" and a RadButton with name "Update", when the grid is loaded the rows will have different status like "pending" "unread" and "cleared". When user selects a row with status pending and clicks on button "update" the status will change from pending to cleared. The issue is when we set a filter on status column with "pending" only rows with pending status are shown, here when user selects a row and click on update the status changes to "cleared", as the filter is already set, the row with the cleared status also shown. As we update the row it is not removed from the grid.

when the filter is set on the grid, filter descriptor is set, when am reloading the grid

```
            dgrid.FilterDescriptors.SuspendNotifications();
            foreach (IColumnFilterDescriptor fd in dgrid.Items.FilterDescriptors)
            {
                //IColumnFilterDescriptor columnFilter = fd;

                Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn col = dgrid.Columns[fd.Column.UniqueName];
                IColumnFilterDescriptor columnFilter = col.ColumnFilterDescriptor;

                columnFilter.FieldFilter.Filter1.Value = fd.FieldFilter.Filter1.Value;
                columnFilter.FieldFilter.Filter1.Operator = fd.FieldFilter.Filter1.Operator;
            }
            dgrid.FilterDescriptors.ResumeNotifications();
           dgrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Store your row items in an `ObservableCollection` of `POCO` objects.
2. Have your `POCO` object class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
3. Bind your `RadGridView` to `ICollectionView` of `POCO` objects contained in your `ObservableCollection`, not the `ObservableCollection` itself.
4. When your `Status` property is changed  `INotifyPropertyChanged` will take care of change notification and all you'll have to do is call `Refresh()` method of your `ICollectionView` and your `RadGridView` will display only items that are specified by the filter...

You might need to apply a few little tweaks along the way but this is a good roadmap to achieving the desired results...

Comment: when I set the filter on the grid, FilterDescriptor is set and when the grid is loaded I want to apply the set filter. I tried this way..updated the question